# Merge two columns result from FILTER

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

In *Google Sheet* I have a sheet similar to this:

```
   A    B   C
   -    -   -
1  A    I   1
2  B    J   0
3  C    K   0
4  D    L   1
5  E    M   1
6  F    N   0
7  G    O   0
8  H    P   1
```

I want to filter this table based on column *C*, if the value is `1` include that row, otherwise excluded it.

Since VLOOKUP can't look on the left I've used this formula to obtain the following result

`=FILTER(A1:B8, C1:C8=1)`

```
E   F
-   -
A   I
D   L
E   M
H   P
```

So far so good.
Now I wanted this result (the two columns E and F) to be merged into a single column, that is, the result I want should be this:

```
E 
-----   
A - I
D - L
E - M
H - P
```

What I have tried so far:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" - ", TRUE, FILTER(A1:B8, C1:C8=1))
```

but it gives me back this result:

```
A - I - D - L - E - M - H - P
```

or

```
=TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(A1:B8, C1:C8=1)),, 9^9))
```

that produces the results I ALMOST want, that is, the result in a single column (good) but I can't add the hyphen symbol:

```
J
-----
A I
D L
E M
H P
```

Link to the [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vQEf4aimu6QPGBw2eoPNR1pdUh_jogGEGvIh_nlPmqx5M5a1dKCcbB8AClLnMPPQvydidIUBoP8HnFb/pub?output=xlsx)

Any suggestion on how to "merge" the two columns from the FILTER result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*You may try this in `Sheets`:*

```js
=FILTER(A:A&" - "&B:B,C:C=1)
```

Comment: wonderful, very simple and effective solution!

Answer (score 2):

Try using <kbd>IFS( )</kbd> & <kbd>TOCOL( )</kbd>

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=TOCOL(IFS(C1:C8,A1:A8&" - "&B1:B8),3)
```

---

The same even works in `Google-Sheets` only needs a <kbd>ARRAYFORMULA()</kbd> wrapping

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D1</kbd>

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(TOCOL(IFS(C1:C8,A1:A8&" - "&B1:B8),3))
```

---